# IllegalThreadStateException OneSignal crash workaround

Tags: android, multithreading, push-notification, thread-safety, onesignal

Our app daily receives around 1k crashes based on bug mentioned on **OneSignal's** [github issues](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/917).

---

**Bug explanation:**

Unfortunately, I can't reproduce this issue. All crashes come from
Crashlytics reports. SDK version 3.12.4

**Devices:**

```
1) Samsung: Galaxy A5(2017), Galaxy S8, Galaxy A50, Galaxy S10+, Galaxy S10  
2) Xiaomi: Mi A2, Mi A2 lite, Mi A1, Mi A3, Redmi Note 5 Pro 
3) Oneplus: ONEPLUS A6010, OnePlus5T, GM191011, GM19008, OnePlus58
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
       at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:724)
       at com.onesignal.OneSignalPrefs$WritePrefHandlerThread.startDelayedWrite(OneSignalPrefs.java:117)
       at com.onesignal.OneSignalPrefs.startDelayedWrite(OneSignalPrefs.java:183)
       at com.onesignal.OneSignal.setAppContext(OneSignal.java:601)
       at com.onesignal.OneSignalSyncServiceUtils.doBackgroundSync(OneSignalSyncServiceUtils.java:175)
       at com.onesignal.SyncJobService.onStartJob(SyncJobService.java:40)
       at android.app.job.JobService$1.onStartJob(JobService.java:62)
       at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobServiceEngine.java:108)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:280)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6748)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

---

**Question:**

The main problem is that they tagged it as medium priority and bug exists around 3 months. Our vitals are going for a toss, just because of this issue. It's costing us a lot.

Does there exist any workaround that can temporary solve the problem?

---

**P.S:**

I'm ready to provide more related info, if required. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The most obvious explanation to me is that you are starting a thread which has already been started. There may be other explanations but this seems the most likely to me.

Comment: @PiRocks I just use OneSignal library, I don’t start any threads

Comment: Are you using the most up to date OneSignal?

Comment: @PiRocks last version 3.12.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug is fixed

---

> The `IllegalThreadStateException` will no longer be thrown in the
>   `3.13.0` Release. You will now see the root exception being thrown
>   instead so these crashes can be diagnosed further.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible(if not likely) that you have an old version of  OneSignal where `synchronized void startDelayedWrite()` is not `synchronized`. In this case I would update, and see if that fixes things. If not see the following:

The exception in question occurs here:

```
synchronized void startDelayedWrite() {
            if (mHandler == null) {
                start();
                mHandler = new Handler(getLooper());
            }
//rest of function irrelevant.
```

The Javadoc for `Thread.start`,states the following:

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

From this and the implementation of `Thread.start`, we can infer that the thread in question is being started twice.

For `this` to be started twice in `startDelayedWrite`, `new Handler(getLooper())` needs to throw an exception, otherwise we won't enter this if statement again. I don't see any way for `getLooper()` to throw an exception, but `new Handler`, certainly can if `getLooper()` is null.

The  implementation of `getLooper()` is as follows:

```
public Looper getLooper() {
        if (!isAlive()) {
            return null;
        }
//rest omitted b/c irrelevant
```

The only way the thread in question could have exited is if `Thread.run` exited early.

The thread's run implementation looks like this:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        mTid = Process.myTid();
        Looper.prepare();
        synchronized (this) {
            mLooper = Looper.myLooper();
            notifyAll();
        }
        Process.setThreadPriority(mPriority);
        onLooperPrepared();
        Looper.loop();
        mTid = -1;
    }
```

`Looper.loop`, is intended to be a semi-infinite loop which reads from a message queue.

Note the following in `Looper.loop`:

```
for (;;) {
            Message msg = queue.next(); // might block
            if (msg == null) {
                // No message indicates that the message queue is quitting.
                return;
            }
```

So if `msg == null`, then our thread exits quickly, possibly causing an exception in `mHandler = new Handler(getLooper());`, resulting in `Thread.start` being called twice.

There are other plausible explanations. For example it is possible that `Looper.loop` crashes at some earlier point.

To mitigate this I would add a `try{} finally{}` block around `mHandler = new Handler(getLooper());`, to handle the case where the `Looper` has already exited. Alternatively I may be wrong and this race condition may be caused by something completely different.

Comment: I was going to post the same answer yesterday, unfortunately, there is no workaround solution for this. Some part of this answer is accurate as `start()` but I don't think that it's a looper issue as the condition to start the thread again is applied on handler as `if (mHandler == null) {` so if the hander is null then it will start it again and cause the exception and many has mentioned that they are using `3.12.6` version with `synchronized` fix. PS: even if the message queue quites, handler instance won't become `null`, right?

Comment: >I was going to post the same answer yesterday, unfortunately, there is no workaround solution for this.

Yeah, if they can't edit the library source I don't think there are any good workarounds, though something might be possible with reflection.

Comment: The point is that `mHandler` remains null after `start();mHandler = new Handler(getLooper());`, because the constructor for `Handler` throws an exception.

Comment: >PS: even if the message queue quites, handler instance won't become null, right?
If the message queue quits before the `Handler` instance is created, then it remains null.

Comment: they did release a version with `synchronized` fix(mentioned earlier) but it's still being called twice. Secondly, I don't any try catch to handle exception so in case of exception, it should crash after not on `start()` method. For solution, question is what is the root cause? the usage of old version has been ruled out(based on github comments) so left with the static thread object and class's instance i/e mhandler initialization issue. `Handler instance is created, then it remains null` how it will reset handler to `null`?

Comment: Right. The `mHandler` is likely not be initialized properly, and the only way that can happen is if `new Handler(getLooper())` throws an exception. The only way that can happen is if `getLooper()` returns null. The most likely reason for that happening is the thread in question no longer being alive, which in turn implies the thread threw or exited early, which is most likely caused by `msg` being null.

Comment: > Handler instance is created, then it remains null how it will reset handler to null?

The handler starts out being null. It is initialized like so: `mHandler = new Handler(getLooper());`, but if `new Handler` throws an exception it remains uninitialized

Comment: `new Handler(getLooper())` return `null`, [Read this and previous comment](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Handler.java#225), where is `RuntimeException`?

Comment: The exception would be on this line: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Handler.java#257
And would be an NPE, because `getLooper` returns null

Comment: Yeah, different constructor, that's the point, it should have been a NPE not illegal state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209152/discussion-between-pirocks-and-pavneet-singh).

Comment: @PiRocks @Pavneet_Singh What do you think about sending pull request to `OneSignal` repo?